# Transform NOT IN to NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql

suppose i have this piece of SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id
FROM PERSON p, ROLE r1
WHERE p.id = r1.id 
AND r1.id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT r.id
    FROM ROLE r, RESTRICTION re
    WHERE r.title = re.title 
    AND r.production_year = re.production_year
    AND (re.description = 'U' OR re.description = 'G')
)
```

I want to convert this to a query where instead of NOT IN a NOT EXISTS.

I did a slight readjustment and made this query but it still didn't work (I got an empty set compared to the result of the first query which returned 200 results (which is correct))

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id
FROM PERSON p, ROLE r1
WHERE p.id = r1.id 
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT DISTINCT r.id
    FROM ROLE r, RESTRICTION re
    WHERE r.title = re.title 
    AND r.production_year = re.production_year
    AND (re.description = 'U' OR re.description = 'G')
    AND r1.id <> r.id
)
```

Why is this wrong? and what do I do to fix it

Comment: Try changing `r1.id <> r.id` to `r1.id = r.id`, you want to say where doesn't exist any record where for this id (`r1.id`)

Answer (score 1):

I would phrase this with the `JOIN` in the subquery.  That way, `SELECT DISTINCT` is not needed in the outer query:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM PERSON p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM ROLE r JOIN
                       RESTRICTION re
                       ON r.title = re.title  AND
                          r.production_year = re.production_year
                  WHERE p.id = r.id AND
                        re.description IN ('U', 'G')
                 );
```

I am really surprised that the `JOIN` condition between `ROLE` and `PERSON` is on `ID`.  But you have provided no sample data or table layouts.

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert `r1.id <> r.id` to `r1.id = r.id` and use ansi-92 SQL format. Because you can match the data by equality of key columns among the main query and subquery.